# Salt extraction from water without affecting mercury concentration

Tags: water, concentration, salt, mercury

I am looking to theoretically *bio-analyze a water sample regarding its mercury concentration* from both sea and lake water using a biosensor with an enzyme biorecognition element. However, a big issue is salt, which can negatively affect the enzyme into the sensor, thus rendering it ineffective. As a result, I would like to filter the salt ions while **at the same time** keeping the mercury in the water. Unfortunately, I am finding it extremely difficult to find a way online of doing precisely this. The relevant papers are either about removing heavy metals like mercury, filtering saltwater, or removing both. Please keep in mind that this is a theoretical exercise and not a real-life experiment, so there's no need to take practical limitations into account. I am not sure this is the right substack to ask this, so thank you for your patience and your answers.

Comment: Aside of the main topic, what form of mercury is to be detected ? As e.g. free mercury, mercury ions and organomercury compouds like $\ce{(CH3)2Hg}$ have very different chemical properties and biological impact.

Comment: You have to think the otherway round and simplify your problem. You have to isolate mercury from a very complex matrix like seawater or lake water because no "sensor" can be so selective that it will respond to parts per billion level of mercurcy and ignore the rest of the junk. For that read about cold vapour mercury analysis, how Hg is isolated.

Comment: As @M.Farooq states, it's far easier to separate the Hg, then use your enzymatic sensor on the Hg-enriched portion.